# Existe alguma forma de fazer @bind-... a uma propriedade readonly em blazor?

Tags: blazor

Existe alguma forma de fazer @bind-... a uma propriedade readonly em blazor?

```
<MyComponent @bind-Property="@ReadOnlyProperty"  />

@code{

 public readonly bool ReadOnlyProperty= true;
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0191  A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a
>   constructor or a variable initializer)

Answer (score -3):

Como você mesmo disse, está usando uma propriedade `readonly`, que sua principal característica é ser imutável. No blazor o `@bind` serve justamente para alterar uma propriedade, esta é sua principal caraterística. Sem criar uma propriedade adicional que não seja somente leitura, eu não vejo forma de conseguir o que você deseja. Espero ter ajudado.